# Erro ao instanciar objeto

Tags: java

no java fx, quando clico no botão, ele deve executar:

```
private void btnLoginClick(ActionEvent event) {
    String name =  txtUser.getText();
    String password = txtPassword.getText();
    User user = new User(name , password);

    if(name == "felipe"){
        System.out.println("Logado");
    } else{
        System.out.println("ERRO AO LOGAR");
    }
}
```

Mas dá erro na hora de instanciar o objeto.

O erro é enorme, vou postar o começo dele:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
```

Comment: O erro indicado é causado por uma invocação de método através de `reflection`. Não tem _nada_ do seu código na pilha de invocação (_stack trace_). Deve ter uma parte mais abaixo com um texto `caused by`, confere?

Comment: Aproveitando: `name == "felipe"` não dará `true` no seu código. Isso porque o operador `==` quando aplicado a objetos verifica se a instância é a mesma, porém a criação da string através do `getText()` gerará (muito possivelmente) uma nova string  partir da cadeia de caracteres guardada no componente. Para compara conteúdo de objetos você deve usar o método `equals`, então o correto seria `"felipe".equals(nome)`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado pela ajuda. Você está certo (Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException).. Quanto ao equals eu tinha descoberto depois, quando a tudo que você falou do reflection e tal, eu realmente não faço ideia do que está falando, sou novato. Vou estudar mais pra entender tudo isso aí e achar uma solução. Valeu (y)